# android media player wont play audio file

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

im making a music app just for fun. I can read all my music files from sd card but MediaPlayer wont play the sound. I have the path to the file which i pass to the media player with `setDataSource` but nothing happens and i get no exceptions. Here is the code im using.

```
Uri songUri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        setUpViews();
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(songUri.toString());
            mp.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ILLEGAL ARGUMENT EXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SECURITY EXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ILLEGAL STATE EXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "IO EXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          mp.start();
          Log.d("URI AFTER SET UP", songUri.toString());
    }
```

As i said before nothing happens when i open this activity but i still get all the Log.d in the console. Is there any more configurations for the media player to play the music? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem, and i just dont know why it works. What i did was to put a button to stop the music being played. I dont understand why it works so if someone could explain why it does i'd be thanksfull.

Answer (score 0):

setDataSource() requires a path argument . You are passing the entire uri as string. Try this :

```
mp.setDataSource(songUri.getPath());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Moreover, if you are trying to access a file with `content://` uri, it won't work. You'll have to find the real path to the file, i.e `file://` uri.

Comment: this is the path a pass to the media player /mnt/sdcard/music/2Pac/Hail Mary.mp3 i tried to aplly what you said but it doesnt work. Any more sugestions? Thanks

Comment: It should work, can you please confirm the audio volume on your device is to the max.

Comment: the volume is to the max. I played the song on the android music player on the phone and it work but it doesnt in my app. I put an if statement like `mp.isPlaying()` and i got `true` i dont know why there's no sound because it seems to be playing. I there any other configuration i should know about? Thanks

Comment: I've worked with MediaPlayer previously and as far as I can say there is no other configuration required. Is it possible for you to check your code on another device?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add [setAudioStreamType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType%28int%29) to your `MediaPlayer` Object. You can add this before `mp.setDataSource(your_URI);` like below

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

There other types, you can choose `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` for Music Player

Answer (score 0):

get the path of song by querying **MEDIASTORE-EXTERNAL_URI**.And this field **MEDIASTORE.AUDIO.MEDIA.DATA** will give u the path of the song(which is string). U can set it directly to **mediaplayer.setDataSource(Your_path_from_mediastore)** .It will work fine than.

Comment: i solved the problem yesterday but thanks for the advice anyway, i appreciate it.